# what does this regular expressions trying to match in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I am a newbie of regular expressions, I try to understand what kind of string of the following regular expressions trying to match:

```
set result [regexp "$PersonName\\|\[^\\n]*\\|\[^\\n]*\\|\\s*0x$PersonId\\|\\s*$gender" [split $outPut \n]]
```

what does the regular expressions above trying to match?what is the value of result?

Comment: not an answer but i'd suggest playing with http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/tcltk/examples/trev/ or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complication here is that the regex specification is protected from the Tcl's string interpolation rules.

To detangle, you should think along these lines:

1. `"$PersonName\\|\[^\\n]*\\|\[^\\n]*\\|\\s*0x$PersonId\\|\\s*$gender"` is a double-quoted string, so the usual interpolation rules apply:

   - Each backslash escapes the following character;
   - Each `$variable` reference is substituted for its value;
   - `[command ...]` is substituted for the string returned by the executed `command`.

   So each occurence of `\\` is there to produce a single '\' character in the interpolated string, and `\[` are meant to prevent Tcl from interpreting those `[^\n]` as commands (named "^\n") to be executed.

   So if we suppose that the `PersonName` variable contains "Joe", `PersonId` contains DEAD and `gender` contains "male", Tcl will get `Joe\|[^\n]*\|[^\n]*\|\s*0xDEAD\|\s*male` after performing all substitutions on the source string.
2. Now the resulting string is passed to the RE engine which applies its own syntacting rules when it parses the string denoting a regex, as described in the [`re_syntax` manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm).

   According to these rules, each backslash, again, escapes the following character unless it's a special "character-entry escape" so here we have:

   - `\s` denotes "any whitespace character";
   - `\|` escapes the '|' making it lose its usual meaning—to introduce an alteration—so that it literally matches the character '|'.

   The `[^\n]*` construct means "a longest series of zero or more characters not including the newline character". Read up on "character classes" in regexes for more info.

Comment: Also, `\s*` means “match any amount of whitespace”.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `result` will be the number of times the regular expression matched. In the absence of the `-all` option, that will always be 0 or 1 (i.e., not-found/found).

Overall, that regular expression (which @kostix's answer explains well) is really ugly though. REs are a powerful tool, but you can get very confused with them very easily. Moreover, if you're splitting the output on newlines then you don't need to try to exclude them in the RE match; there will *definitely* be no newlines in the result of `split` in that case.

If we better understood what you were trying to do, we could direct you to far more effective methods of matching (e.g., using `lsearch` with suitable options, loading the data into an in-memory SQLite database).